# Looking at Sales Data. How to determine if an order was a new order or a reorder for a specific customer and product?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Data I possess: Transaction Date (A:A), Customer Name (B:B), Sales Order Number (C:C), Product Name (D:D), Units (E:E), Revenue (F:F)

New order would be anything that the customer hasn't ordered in the past 6 months or ever.

A reorder would be if the customer had purchased that specific product in the past 6 months.

I can't wrap my head around how to put this logic into an excel formula.

Comment: what I've realized that, before accept New order the Date should be tested if hasn't find within 6 months then okay. But unable to understand second one,, *"A reorder would be if the customer had purchased that specific product in the past 6 months".* seems both are contradictions!!

Comment: **Cont...** or would you like to set 2 Criteria for New Order,, 1. Date and 2. Product !!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I’m misunderstanding something, but this seems to be fairly simple. 
My understanding of the question is that a row represents a reorder
if there is at least one row above the current one
that has the same Customer Name (Column `B`) as the current row,
the same Product Name (Column `D`), and a Transaction Date (Column `A`)
within the past six months of the current Transaction Date. 
Columns `C`, `E` and `F` can be ignored. 
I assume that the rows are sorted by Transaction Date
(although I guess I don’t need to make that assumption).

The Transaction Date criterion is the “hardest” (I use that term loosely). 
A past date is within the past six months of `A2` if it is

```
> EDATE(A2,-6)
```

So, to count the rows through the current one
that satisfy the three criteria, we use

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, ">" & EDATE(A2,-6), B$2:B2, B2, D$2:D2, D2)
```

The `A$2:A2` notation is interesting. 
It represents a range that starts in Row 2 and ends in the current row;
i.e., everything up through (and including) the current row. 
This count will always be at least 1, because the current row counts. 
If it’s greater than 1,
there was at least one previous row that also matched. 
So the answer is to enter

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, ">" & EDATE(A2,-6), B$2:B2, B2, D$2:D2, D2)<=1, "New Order", "Reorder")
```

into `H2` (or wherever you want it) and drag/fill down.

[image: spreadsheet showing the count and the interpretation of the count]

---

If the rows might be out of order, we need to search the entire table
and test that the date is less than the current date:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$99, ">" & EDATE(A2,-6), A$2:A$99, "<" & A2,
                                           B$2:B$99, B2, D$2:D$99, D2)=0, "New Order", "Reorder")
```

where I’m using `99` to represent the last row of the data. 
I changed the test from `<=1` to `=0`
because the `< A2` test eliminates the current row. 
If your data might include multiple rows
with the same Customer Name and Product Name,
and the exact same Transaction Date,
please specify how they should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're gonna love this one.

I'll break it down into steps because the final formula is going to be fairly complex.

### Setup

I created a worksheet in the format you specified. I've added three columns to piece out what we need to do, which I'll describe individually below. Note that I've frozen the top row and scrolled down a bit in this first screenshot.

[image: worksheet]

### Step 1: Establish range to search

First we need to know when 6 months ago was (and where in the spreadsheet that date is located). In each record, we'll use `EDATE` to find out.

In cell `G2`:

`VLOOKUP(EDATE(A2,-6),A:A,1,TRUE)`

This is great - this gives us the last sales record we have that was more than 6 months ago. Note that if you have infrequent sales (ie. big gaps between sales records), the way that I've written this does mean you might 'catch' false positives, if the last order of the item in question was, say, 6 months and a week ago AND there were no orders at all between 6 months and a week ago and exactly 6 weeks ago. I decided this was 'close enough' for you.

The only other flaw is there are some unpleasing-looking errors near the top of the sheet, because for the first record (ie. row `2`) there are no 6-months-ago records at all. So let's wrap with an `IFERROR`:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(EDATE(A2,-6),A:A,1,TRUE),$A$2)`

In other words, tell me when the most recent order more than 6 months ago was, unless there isn't one, in which case just give me the first order we have record of.

This formula copies down. That's here:

[image: helper1]

### Step 2: Turn that range-starting data into a cell location

In cell `H2`:

`=MATCH(G2,A:A,0)`

This one's easy. In what ordinal location in column `A` do we find the 6-months-ago date we established in Step 1?

This formula copies down. Here we are:

[image: helper2]

### Step 3: Do it

Let's skip ahead and put this into, how about, `I21`, so we can see how it works.

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&H21&":D"&ROW()-1),MATCH(D21,INDIRECT("D"&H21&":D"&ROW()-1),0),1)`

This is, at base, just a simple `INDEX` `MATCH` search. But what we've done is replace the cell references of the arrays of those functions with `INDIRECT` references to the value we just seeded into column `H`.

In my sample data, row `21` is a sales record with a date of `10/1/2018`. Column `G` finds the most recent sales record more than 6 months prior to that date, which in my sample date happens to be `4/1/2018`.  Column `H` pegs the (first) location of that date in column `A` at the 8th row. Thus `INDIRECT("A"&H21&` says to start the array for the search at the row in `A` identified by the value in `H`. Nice! And the other half of the `INDIRECT`, `":D"&ROW()-1)` says to end the array at the row in `D` that's one row above the record we're presently in.

In other words, you could write

`=INDEX(A1:D999,MATCH(D21,D1:D9999,0),1)`

To find the first incidence of your product code in `D` over the ENTIRE sales ledger - but we don't want to do that. So we replace the cell references with dynamic ranges that we've used the previous two steps to generate. With me?

So that looks like this:

[image: find match]

Once we copy that formula (wrapped in another `IFERROR` for appearances) up to row `2` and back down, you've got:

[image: Frankenstein]

There's a false positive on the first row. I'm going to live with that, too.

### Step 4: Combine

So the formula in `I` references `H`, which references `G`. Reverse expansion nets a final formula that reads:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(EDATE(A2,-6),A:A,1,TRUE),$A$2),A:A,0)&":D"&ROW()-1),MATCH(D2,INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(EDATE(A2,-6),A:A,1,TRUE),$A$2),A:A,0)&":D"&ROW()-1),0),1),"NEW ORDER")`

And looks like:

[image: Grand finale]

So, if you like, you can just copy that formula into your 'reorder' column in row `2` and copy down.

### NB.

1. You're going to use Format Painter on your output field, because the formulas as written will treat the text dates in `A` as date serial numbers, and return a serial number as well.
2. Note the weakness in Step 1 - you can see in the screenshot of the `helper1` field in Step 3 that in my sample data, the 6-months-ago date for 10/1 was 4/1 and the 6-months-ago date for 10/5 was *also* 4/1, because there were no orders at all between 4/1 and 4/5. This could potentially call out false positives.
3. Again, as discussed in Step 3 there's also going to be a false positive on the first sales record using this method.

Comment: Ooh, bad job by me to miss that. I'm sorry! Don't worry about having a lot to learn, this is a fairly advanced request, actually. I can figure a way to integrate the matching of customer and product ID but I won't be able to get to it til Monday.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbtkgj1tqfvx10l/Sales_Data_Test_Small.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

*My approach is bit different to solve the issue, since I've picked OP's thread,,*

1. **New order would be anything that the customer 
    hasn't ordered in the past 6 months or ever.**
2. **A reorder would be if the customer had 
     purchased that specific product in the past 
     6 months.**

---

[image]

- An Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `H41`, finish 
  with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

`{=IFERROR(LOOKUP(DATEDIF(IFERROR(INDEX($A$41:$A$47,MATCH(1,($B$41:$B$47=J41)*($D$41:$D$47=K41),0)),"No Match"),I41,"m"),{0,6,12},{"New Order","Order before 6 month","Order before 12 months"}),"Cust's.  New Pro. Order")}`

---

**Situation 1:**

New Traction Date: `03/26/19`.

Customer Name: `Bob`.

Product's Name: `Cake`.

Order Sataus: `Order before 12 months`.

[image]

---

**Situation 2:**

New Traction Date: `03/26/19`.

Customer Name: `Bob`.

Product's Name: `Milk`.

Order Sataus: `New Order`.

[image]

**N.B.**

*Because difference between Old Transaction Date (`10/01/18`) and New Transaction Date (`03/26/19`) is less than 6 Months.*

---

**Situation 3:**

New Traction Date: `03/26/19`.

Customer Name: `Bob`.

Product's Name: `Wheat`.

Order Sataus: `Order before 6 months`.

[image]

**Situation 4:**

New Traction Date: `03/26/19`.

Customer Name: `Bob`.

Product's Name: `Fruit`.

Order Sataus: `Cust's. New Pro.Order`.

[image]

---

**Note:**

*If you enter new Customer's Name and either Old or New Product and Date you get `Cust's . New Pro. Order` as status.*

[image]

---

**Now let me explain how the Formula works.**

*Formula can be divide into two parts.*

`Part 1`

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$41:$A$47,MATCH(1,($B$41:$B$47=J41)*($D$41:$D$47=K41),0)),"No Match")}
```

*Basically it's 2 Criteria Lookup which finds `Old Transaction Date` for `Customer & the Product`, and the Formula considers it as `Start Date` for `DATEDIF` formula is within `A41:A47`..*

`Part 2`

The original `DATEDIF` is,

```
{=LOOKUP(DATEDIF(A41:A47,I41,"m"),{0,6,12},{"New order","Order before 6 month","Order before 12 months"})}
```

*Where `A41:A47` is been replaced with the `Part 1` Formula as `Start Date` and the `End Date` is in cell `I41`.*

And both parts are nicely wrapped with `IFERROR`.

**N.B**

- You may adjust cell references as needed.
- Messages with the Formula alos can be altered 
  as your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IF( SUM( ($B$2:$B9=A10) * ($D$2:$D9=D10) * ($A$2:$A9>($A10-183)) ) = 0, "New", "Reorder" )
```

It uses the old school technique of simple "range=" tests to produce arrays that tell you each thing (Is the customer's name in any cell in the column A range? Is the product name in the column D range? Are the dates in the column A range within 183 days of today's order?) and then multiplies them to get a final array.

The raw array values are TRUE/FALSE values, but multiplying them coerces Excel to change them to 1/0 values which multiply nicely. The end result is an array with 1's where all three of the above conditions are met and 0's where that is not so. Excel does not convert the array's elements back to TREU/FALSE values so the entire array is numerical.

`SUM` then sums them all up into a single value. If the result is anything except 0, then at least one same order exists in the last 183 days. If 0, then none such exist. The `IF` simply checks which result it is and tells you "New" or "Reorder".

Really the only point of interest is the mixture of absoluteness vs. relativeness in the range addressing. All the range starting points are fully absolute so the upper left corner of each range is anchored, unmoving. The range ending points only make the column of the reference absolute so that the range grows as you add rows, but never includes the current row... so starts at the top and ends one row above the current row.

If not clear from the start, I posit the information appearing in the column G cell of the order just entered's row. However, it could be elsewhere including not even in the same row, nor the same sheet, and could be used in making a Conditional Formatting test to change row cell colors to show "New/Reorder" in that manner.